# Can we force dhclient to not renew ip rules?

Tags: linux, networking, redhat, rhel5, dhclient

I've overridden the ip routing rules on my RHEL machine by adding custom logic in a new script ifup-local that is run immediately after a new interface is attached.

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth executes dhclient with lease times for each interface.  At the end of a lease period dhclient tries to update the ip rules which conflict with my settings.

Is there a way I can avoid this? As a work-around I've also written a script that runs at the same time as dhclient and removes the new rules written by dhclient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dhclient-script](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient-script) and its hooks to override the route configuration.

For example, add this line to /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/no-default-route:

> unset new_routers

So the default gateway does not get set. You can add any logic you want in this script.

Comment: I don't have any such file on my RHEL machine. Isn't this true for Debian or Ubuntu?